How to set global Python interpreter in VSCode
 As you can see from the image, 3.11.9 is the global; I would like to set 3.12.4 as the default.
I tried moving the Python path from environment variables to the top, but it doesn't work. For some reason, the default the Python version is not in sync with the global version of Python interpreter in VSCode.

If you just want to change the global environment, you could use Python version management tool, such as pyenv or pythonbrew.
To select the above-mentioned newly-installed Python 3.12.4 as your preferred version to use:
pyenv global 3.12.4

However, in Python, it is best practice to create a workspace-specific environment, such as conda or virtual environment.
You could read VSCode Python document about environment for moe details.
